# joomla 3.3: "Could not connect to MySQL."

Tags: joomla, connection

I tried to download an existing joomla 3.3 project to my local xampp htdocs folder. I copied the database and changed the database connection data in configuration.php

Afterwards it seemed to work, frontend and backend login works perfectly, but as soon as I navigate to another page (/index.php?option=com_fabrik&view=list&listid=25&Itemid=112) I get a nicely styled error page which says "Could not connect to MySQL."

I tried to google this, but it's not like this is a blank page with the error message. The connection to the database must be at least partially working, otherwise I wouldn't be able to login and I wouldn't get such a nice HTML Error page in the same design as the rest of the page.

I am absolutely new to joomla. How can I find out what the problem is? Any hints, ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just "solved" my own problem. Turns out that "fabrik" has its own database connection data. In /administrator I navigated to components - fabrik - connections and edited "site database" there. And now it works!